# The <front> route 's path

Tags: views, 8, routes

My `<front>` and `<none>` route is now using one of my view path... I think it's because I delete the default home view.

I don't need it because my home page is a Panels Page...

How to set the `<front>` route to use an other path ?

EDIT :

Exemple: 
i've a view called myContentAdminView, with this url defined : /my-content-admin-view.

if i look in the bdd, in the router table, the both path of the  front> and  none> route are set to  /my-content-admin-view. this values are sync with the url view, i don't know why and how to change that.

The front> is use for exemple when you disconect. 
The none> route is use by the MenuBlock to check if a user has the right to see a link with no route (like this one : '#a-anchor-link')

Comment: You want `<front>` to be your panel page? or something else?

Comment: it's already done in the base site parameters configuration. But the <front> route is the one use for exemple when you are disconected, aperently.

Comment: Also when you add a link in a menu tree with a url like this : "#my-anchor-link", the system check the <none> route to see if a user can see it. For me anoymous people can't see the link...because the <none> route is attached with a administration view xD

Answer (score 2):

The defaults for these routes are defined in system.routing.yml:

```
'<front>':
  path: '/'
  defaults:
    _title: Home
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

'<none>':
  path: ''
  options:
    _no_path: TRUE
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

The router table is rebuilt every time you clear the cache. Then all static routes defined in yaml-files are collected and put in the router table.

If you get other path values for these routes, then you must have overridden this somewhere, for example in a view.

This has nothing to do with the setting in site configuration.

If you a looking for a specific path you can search in all `*.routing.yml` files for the static routes. Most of the dynamically generated routes probably are somewhere in the config files. You can export the full config of your site (admin/config/development/configuration/full/export) and search there for a specific string.

Comment: yes, I think i did it in my view, because it's the path of my view. How did i change that? I don't remember did anyting about that expect to delete the home page view. I don't found any option about it :s

Comment: I added some ideas how you can try to find the path.

Comment: I allready search in those file...nothing founed. It's someting else. It's using a specific bloc in a specific view, since i deleted the front page.